# Erro ao tentar publicar webjob no Azure

Tags: visual-studio-2015, microsoft-azure

Estou tentando fazer a publicação de um webjob no Azure e até a parte da publicação está tudo certo. Ele consegue publicar e consigo rodar o Webjob normalmente, porém quando ele tenta agendar o Webjob no modelo "Scheduled" ele lança o erro abaixo e não consegue deixar no modo Scheduled voltando para o modo On Demand.

Erro lançado ao tentar publicar o webjob

> Error : An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: Response
>   status code does not indicate success: 409 (Conflict).

Alguém sabe o que pode estar ocorrendo?

Meu webjob-publish-settings.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "assinatura",
  "startTime": "2016-03-14T00:00:00-03:00",
  "endTime": null,
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Hour",
  "interval": 1,
  "runMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Diego,

você precisa adicionar uma propriedade chamada **schedule** no arquivo **settings.job**, da uma olhada neste guia aqui para mais detalhes https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs#scheduling-a-triggered-webjob

Comment: Bom dia William, obrigado pela resposta.
Estou com ele no modelo Scheduled já, porém nem assim consigo publicar ele
Inclui também meu webjob-publish-settings.json no texto acima